# Get string between two same words in Scala Regex

Tags: regex, scala, parsing

I'm trying to write a regex parser in Scala that will grab everything between two specified words (same words in this case). Here is the parser I wrote:

```
def getBatchModules: Parser[String] = """(?s)(?=--batch.*?(?=--batch))""".r
```

The input is the following:

```
val tempVal = "--batch_123123\n--batch_222222-\n--batch_asdkokasdj"
```

And I want my parser to extract *--batch_123123* from it.

When I run my code I get

```
string matching regex `\z' expected but `-' found

--batch_123123

^
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What about `(?s)--batch.+?(?=--batch.*$)`? Or even `(?s)--batch_\w+(?=--batch.*$)`? I also think the problem is with the 3rd `--batch`, that's why I suggest adding `.*$`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify your regex and use another like this:

```
(?s)--batch(.*?)--batch
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/qW5gV4/1)**

Then access to the capturin group like this:

```
val string = "--batch_123123\n--batch_222222-\n--batch_asdkokasdj"
val pattern = """(?s)--batch(.*?)--batch""".r
pattern.findAllIn(string).matchData foreach {
   m => println(m.group(1))
}
```